# How to draw two error bars at one point in Mathematica?

Tags: graphics

[image: The thick error bars indicates interval of 68% probability and the thin ones denotes 98%]

I have read the error bars reference in Mathematica to find how to draw a picture like the one above(The thick error bars indicates interval of 68% probability and the thin ones denotes 98%), but I only find the method to draw like the following picture:

[image]

or like this:

[image]

And both are not that I want to draw. How can I draw a picture with a thick error bar and a thin one at one point like Fig.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some improvement. I assume that you data is in this form;

> {1, 1.72224, 2.2189, 0.941405}

First two are your data point. Third entry is %98 error and fourth entry is %68 error.

```
SeedRandom@2;
    data = {#, # + RandomReal[1], RandomReal[{2, 4}], 
         RandomReal[{0.5, 2}]} & /@ Range[10];
    dist = 0.05; thicness = 0.004;
    ListLinePlot[data[[All, {1, 2}]], Mesh -> Full, MeshStyle -> Red, 
     PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {-1, 13}, 
     Epilog -> {{{Red, 
           Line[{{#[[1]], #[[2]] - #[[3]]}, {#[[1]], #[[2]] + #[[3]]}}], 
           Thickness[thicness], 
           Line[{{#[[1]], #[[2]] - #[[4]]}, {#[[1]], #[[2]] + #[[4]]}}], 
           Line[{{#[[1]] - dist, #[[2]] - #[[4]]}, {#[[1]] + 
               dist, #[[2]] - #[[4]]}}], 
           Line[{{#[[1]] - dist, #[[2]] + #[[4]]}, {#[[1]] + 
               dist, #[[2]] + #[[4]]}}]} & /@ data}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Although we could think to use the extra package `ErrorBarPlots`, the problem here is the limited use of the error bars and its styling.

This can be a starting point:

```
data = {#, # + RandomReal[0.5]} & /@ Range[10];
data1 = {data[[1]], data[[5]]};

err1 = 0.9; err2 = 1.7;

ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {-1, 11}, Frame -> True, 
Epilog -> {{Red, Line[{{#[[1]], #[[2]] - err2}, {#[[1]], #[[2]] + err2}}] & /@ 
 data1}, 
{Blue, Line[{{#[[1]], #[[2]] - err1}, {#[[1]], #[[2]] + err1}}] & /@ 
 data1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!