# Changing error bars color

Tags: plotting, style, marker

I have the following plot

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
Show[Plot [{ 
2 10^3 x  (4 4^2 + (y^2 - R^2 ))/(y^2 - R^2 )^3 /. R -> 3} /. 
FindRoot[
y == Subscript[ω, 0]
     Sqrt[1 + 
     57 Subscript[ω, 0]/
       y (1/(Exp[y/x] - 1) + 1/2 - 
        y/(2 Subscript[ω, 0]))] /. {Subscript[ω, 
   0] -> 23}, {y, 1}], {x, 0, 300}, 
PlotStyle -> {Blue}], {ErrorListPlot[{{290, 0.012263719, 
 0.002}, {240, 0.007675481, 0.002}, {220, 0.008038809, 
 0.002}, {200, 0.008608707, 0.002}, {170, 0.010805872, 
 0.002}, {150, 0.008832903, 0.002}, {130, 0.009263129, 
 0.002}, {120, 0.011290667, 0.002}, {100, 0.014344114, 
 0.002}, {40, 0.025720622, 0.002}, {30, 0.028876792, 0.002}, {20, 
 0.035088327, 0.002}, {15, 0.042578946, 0.002}, {4.2, 
 0.033039767, 0.002}}]}]
```

And the output is:

[image: errorbar]

**How can I change the color of points and also error bars?**

Comment: add the option `PlotStyle -> Red` to `ErrorListPlot`?

Comment: @kglr already did that but it doesn't work

Comment: Kassik, it works both  in v9 (windows10) and v11.3 (Wolfram Cloud). You can also try post-processing `ErrorListPlot` output using `ErrorListPlot[....] /. /. lp : (_Line | _Point) :> {Red, lp}`. (This also works both in v9 and  in v11.3)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the sub-option `"LineColor"` in `PlotStyle` to have the error lines and the plot markers have different colors:

```
plot = Plot[{2 10^3 x (4 4^2 + (y^2 - R^2))/(y^2 - R^2)^3 /.  R -> 3} /. 
    FindRoot[y == Subscript[ω, 0] Sqrt[1 + 57 Subscript[ω, 0]/ y (1/(Exp[y/x] - 1) + 
      1/2 - y/(2 Subscript[ω, 0]))] /. {Subscript[ω, 0] -> 23}, 
  {y, 1}], {x, 0, 300}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}];

Show[plot, ErrorListPlot[data, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, PointSize[Large], Red, "LineColor" -> Green]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"];
With[
 {
  data = {
    {290, 0.012263719, 0.002}, {240, 0.007675481, 0.002},
    {220, 0.008038809, 0.002}, {200, 0.008608707, 0.002},
    {170, 0.010805872, 0.002}, {150, 0.008832903, 0.002},
    {130, 0.009263129, 0.002}, {120, 0.011290667, 0.002},
    {100, 0.014344114, 0.002}, {40, 0.025720622, 0.002},
    {30, 0.028876792, 0.002}, {20, 0.035088327, 0.002},
    {15, 0.042578946, 0.002}, {4.2, 0.033039767, 0.002}
    }
  },
 Show[
  Plot[
   {2 10^3 x (4 4^2 + (y^2 - R^2))/(y^2 - R^2)^3 /. R -> 3}
    /. FindRoot[
     y == ωo Sqrt[
         1 + 57 ωo/
            y (1/(Exp[y/x] - 1) + 1/2 - 
             y/(2 ωo))] /. {ωo -> 23}
     , {y, 1}
     ]
   , {x, 0, 300}
   , PlotStyle -> {Blue}
   , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
   ],
  ErrorListPlot[
   data
   , PlotStyle -> Red
   , PlotMarkers -> None
   ],
  ListPlot[
   data[[All, {1, 2}]]
   , PlotStyle -> Black]
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Side note:** I suggest you avoid using `Subscript`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own Error plot. See [this.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/169739/how-to-draw-two-error-bars-at-one-point-in-mathematica/169758#169758) Play with `dist = 0.8; thickness = 0.003`

```
    data = {{290, 0.012263719, 0.002}, {240, 0.007675481, 0.002}, {220, 
        0.008038809, 0.002}, {200, 0.008608707, 0.002}, {170, 0.010805872,
         0.002}, {150, 0.008832903, 0.002}, {130, 0.009263129, 
        0.002}, {120, 0.011290667, 0.002}, {100, 0.014344114, 0.002}, {40,
         0.025720622, 0.002}, {30, 0.028876792, 0.002}, {20, 0.035088327, 
        0.002}, {15, 0.042578946, 0.002}, {4.2, 0.033039767, 0.002}};

    p1 = Plot[ {2 10^3 x (4 4^2 + (y^2 - R^2))/(y^2 - R^2)^3 /. R -> 3}
    /. FindRoot[
     y == ωo Sqrt[
         1 + 57 ωo/
            y (1/(Exp[y/x] - 1) + 1/2 - 
             y/(2 ωo))] /. {ωo -> 23}
     , {y, 1}
     ]
   , {x, 0, 300}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
       Frame -> True];
    p2 = ListPlot[data[[All, {1, 2}]], PlotStyle -> Red,
      ];
    dist = 0.8; thickness = 0.003;
    p3 = Graphics[{{Green, Thickness[thickness], 
           Line[{{#[[1]], #[[2]] - #[[3]]}, {#[[1]], #[[2]] + #[[3]]}}], 
           Line[{{#[[1]] - dist, #[[2]] - #[[3]]}, {#[[1]] + 
               dist, #[[2]] - #[[3]]}}], 
           Line[{{#[[1]] - dist, #[[2]] + #[[3]]}, {#[[1]] + 
               dist, #[[2]] + #[[3]]}}]} & /@ data}];

    Show[{p1, p3, p2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]