# Where can I download the ErrorBar Plotting Package?

Tags: plotting, graphics, warning-messages

I'm trying to find the link to download the ErrorBar Plotting Package but I just can't seem to find it.

The only link I have is the following:
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ErrorBarPlots/guide/ErrorBarPlottingPackage.html

I have found some custom made Packages for error plotting but it would be really nice if I could use this simple Error Package.

Comment: Why not use `Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]`?

Comment: See also this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/179253/changing-error-bars-color/179260#179260

Comment: Oh, I thought I had to install an extra package, my bad. Thanks for the quick answers!

Answer (score 3):

There is a tiny typo in the comment by @ThatGravityGuy due to syntax highlighting. Should be:

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
```

This is what the documentation applies to.

Comment: Oh, I thought I had to install an extra package, my bad. Thanks for the quick answers!