# Plotting ListStepPlot with error bar

Tags: plotting

I would like to plot `ListStepPlot` with error bar.

here the whole case : I am starting with data table `{x1,x2,x3,....xn}`. I need to integrate it "by part" (summing the `n` first value, then the `n` following etc.) and then plotting the result of the integrals in the form of a `ListStepPlot` so no problem there. But I want error bars on the step.

Is there a simple way to do that ?  ( to be sure : my question is only about display, it is not the maths behind the error bar).

(I can using `BarChart` but bars are separated so it is not exactly what I need or `ErrorListPlot` with zero degree interpolation but the dots and error bars are not at the center of the step but on the edges so it does not look so good)

Thanks for you help !

Comment: Can you add an example of what you currently have (as copyable code) to the question? (ideally with a mock-up of what you would like it to look in the end) - That would make it significantly easier to help you.

Comment: What about ErrorBar, see https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ErrorBarPlots/ref/ErrorBar.html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** In versions 12.0+ you do not need  the `` "ErrorBarPlots`" `` package. You can use [`Around`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html) to construct a new data set that can be used directly with `ListStepPlot` :

```
data2 = {#, Around[##2]} & @@@ data;

ListStepPlot[data2, Center,   
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]], 
 Mesh -> {data2[[All, 1]]}, 
 IntervalMarkersStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can combine `ListStepPlot` and `ErrorListPlot` as follows (using `data` from Okkes Dulgerci's answer):

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"] 
lsp = ListStepPlot[data[[All, {1, 2}]], Center];
elp = ErrorListPlot[data, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05], PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red, LineColor -> Purple],
   Prolog -> lsp[[1]]] /. {p_Point, x__} :> {x, p}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can modify the input data and use `ErrorListPlot` with a combination of options `InterpolationOrder`, `Mesh` and `ErrorBarFunction`:

```
ErrorListPlot[Join[{-.5, 0, 0} + # & /@ data, {{.5, 0} + data[[-1, ;; 2]]}], 
 Joined -> True, InterpolationOrder -> 0, Mesh -> {data[[All, 1]]}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red],
 ErrorBarFunction -> ({Purple, ErrorBarPlots`Private`ebarfun[{.5, 0} + #, ##2]} &)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

How about this? 3rd coordinate is error. see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/179253/changing-error-bars-color/179260#179260).

```
   data = {{1, 0.012263719, 0.002}, {2, 0.007675481, 0.002}, {3, 
    0.008038809, 0.002}, {4, 0.008608707, 0.002}, {5, 0.010805872, 
    0.002}, {6, 0.008832903, 0.002}, {7, 0.009263129, 0.002}, {8, 
    0.011290667, 0.002}, {9, 0.014344114, 0.002}, {10, 0.025720622, 
    0.002}, {11, 0.028876792, 0.002}, {12, 0.035088327, 0.002}};
dist = 0.1; thicness = 0.003;
p = Graphics[{{Black, Thickness[thicness], 
       Line[{{#[[1]], #[[2]] - #[[3]]}, {#[[1]], #[[2]] + #[[3]]}}], 
       Line[{{#[[1]] - dist, #[[2]] - #[[3]]}, {#[[1]] + 
           dist, #[[2]] - #[[3]]}}], 
       Line[{{#[[1]] - dist, #[[2]] + #[[3]]}, {#[[1]] + 
           dist, #[[2]] + #[[3]]}}]} & /@ data}, PlotRange -> All];

Show[{DensityPlot[, {x, 0.5, 12.5}, {y, 0, 0.04}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio], p, 
  ListStepPlot[data[[All, {1, 2}]], Center], 
  ListPlot[data[[All, {1, 2}]], 
   PlotStyle -> {AbsolutePointSize@6, Red}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what i want. Thank you !I am just a bit surprise there is not a more advance dedicated error bar tool !

Comment: @Dalnor There is - see another answer